# React Native how to setState data inside data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

For example:

We have in the constructor the avatar data, inside the avatar there is thumb and inside the thumb the url. I just want to get the url. anyone has any hint to spare?

```
{avatar: {:thumb{:url}}}


   constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            id: "",
            avatar: "",
            bio: "",
            error: "",
        }
    }
```

[image]

fetched user data

```
  async fetchUserId()  {

         let auth_token = await AsyncStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN);



  fetch("https://xxx.herokuapp.com/api/users/"+auth_token+"", {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },

}).then((response) => response.json())
   .then((json) => {


    this.state.id = json.id

//this.state.url =  json.avatar.thumb.url



  })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update a nested state in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-a-nested-state-in-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

you're not setting `json.id` and `json.avatar` correctly to the state you need to use `setState`

```
this.setState({ id: json.id,avatar: json.avatar })
```

**Solution one**

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            id: "",
            avatar: {},
            bio: "",
            error: "",
            url: ""
        }

    }

getUrl = () =>{
if(this.state.avatar && this.state.avatar.thumb && this.state.avatar.thumb.url){
      this.setState({ url: this.state.avatar.thumb.url })
   } 
}

<button onClick={this.getUrl}>Get URL </button>
```

**Solution Two**

Because `avatar` is coming from async I suggest you to use `componentWillUpdate` lifecycle method

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
   if(this.state.avatar !== nextState.avatar){
     console.log(nextState.avatar.thumb.url)
   }
}
```

> Note: `componentWillUpdate` will invoket on everytime that `this.state.avatar` changes

Comment: Liam, thank you very much for your interest and answer but after i added your answer show this error in the logs

TypeError: TypeError: TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.state.avatar.thumb.url')

Comment: I just edit my answer. Is `avatar` data coming from async operation?

Comment: i'm fetching and parsing into json

Comment: but anyway thank you very much for your time and patience

Comment: wait a minute   just let check this avatar: {}

Comment: this (evaluating '_this.state.avatar.thumb.url')

Comment: Ok no worries, I will edit my answer, this occurs because `avatar` data isn't exist yet.

Comment: liam thank you, i update the question as well, as you was wondering how i was get the user data

Comment: @lula check now

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot mutate the state, and since setState doesn't handle nested updates, you need to use the following code to set such a state:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    avatar: {
        ...prevState.avatar,
        thumb: {
           ...prevState.avatar.thumb,
           url: newUrlValue
        }
    }
}))
```

Comment: The `...prevState` before `avatar: {` is not necessary because `setState` automatically handles that.

Comment: Rahamin, thank you but in newUrlValue should i place the fetched data?

Comment: Which data do you fetch? A url? Then, yes. From your state definition I understood that you want to know how to set the url value inside the state...

Answer (score 0):

Like This You can set:-

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    stars: "",
    icon: "",
      longitude: "",
    address:"",
     latitude: "",
    trails: [], isLoaded: false
  }




  handleChange = address => {
   this.setState({
      address

    });

        geocodeByAddress(address)
            .then(res => getLatLng(res[0]))
      .then(({ lat, lng }) => {
    this.setState({

      latitude: lat,
      longitude: lng,

    });
  })
 .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ isGeocoding: false });
        console.log('error', error); // eslint-disable-line no-console
      });

 }

  getUser = selected => {

var object = this.refs.Progress2;

object.innerHTML="";


 this.setState({ isGeocoding: true, address: selected });
```